# Создание нескольких контролов по кнопке

Tags: c#, winforms

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как сделать так, чтобы при нажатии на кнопку в определенной области создавались несколько контролов, расположенных рядом.

Например текстбокс, лейбл, текстбокс и снова лейбл, как на картинке ниже.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

И при повторном нажатии добавлялись такие же "строчки", только ниже.

Платформа Windows Forms.

Comment: Если вы задаете такие вопросы, то вам стоит сначала почитать про  Windows Forms. Например тут: https://metanit.com/sharp/windowsforms/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Спасибо за советы, я разобрался.

Необходимо программно инициализировать все контролы и панель, на которую их необходимо помесить, а затем уже работать с этой панелью.

```
private void AddButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var p = new Panel
        {
            Location = new Point(X, _y),
            Size = new Size(150, 30)
        };
        var t1 = new TextBox
        {
            Location = new Point(5, 5),
            Size = new Size(30, 20)
        };
        var l1 = new Label
        {
            Text = @"= f",
            Location = new Point(35, 8),
            Size = new Size(20, 20)
        };
        var t2 = new TextBox
        {
            Location = new Point(55, 5),
            Size = new Size(30, 20)
        };
        var l2 = new Label
        {
            Text = @",",
            Location = new Point(85, 8),
            Size = new Size(10, 20)
        };
        var t3 = new TextBox
        {
            Location = new Point(95, 5),
            Size = new Size(30, 20)
        };
        p.Controls.Add(t1);
        p.Controls.Add(l1);
        p.Controls.Add(t2);
        p.Controls.Add(l2);
        p.Controls.Add(t3);
        MainPanel.Controls.Add(p);
        _y += 30;
    }
```

И вот результат.

[image: Результат]

Comment: Молодец! Желаю дальнейших успехов.

Answer (score 3):

"создавались" - оператор `new`

"в определенной области" - `parent.Controls.Add()`

"расположенных рядом" - `Control.Location`

"объединить их в группу" - создать контрол `Panel`, на который положить более мелкие контролы; более ОО подход - создать свой `UserControl`

Comment: Я имею ввиду, имеется ли какой-либо способ объединить их в группу и манипулировать в дальнейшем как группой (добавлять/удалять).